# Passing pointer to an object in BeginThread method

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have basic classes like following:

```
Type
Test = class

end;

TestIpl = class (Test)

end
```

Then I create object:

```
obj = TestIpl.Create();
```

Now I would like to pass this object to BeginThread, which goes like this:

```
BeginThread(nil, 0, @mtd, obj, 0, Threadinfo.ThreadId);
```

In method: mtd I would like to use created object, so I cast this like this:

```
var 
  obj: Test;
begin
obj :=  Test(DataParameter);
```

Am I doing this correctly, but what's more important. Can it be done like this?
I am anxious about the line which casts pointer to its original object. Will it work this way?

Currently, I get AV when I want to use overloaded method in testIpl.
Thanks

EDIT

```
function mtd(DataParameter: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
```

**TEST CASE**

```
unit Unit2;

interface

Type
  Test = class
  protected
    function Test(): Integer; virtual;
  end;

  TestIpl = class (Test)
  protected
    function Test(): Integer; override;
  end;

procedure TestCase;

implementation

function RunThread(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;
var
  x: Test;
  Rslt: Integer;
begin
  x := Test(Parameter);

  Rslt := x.Test();
end;


procedure TestCase;
var
  test: TestIpl;
  ThreadId: Cardinal;
begin
  test := TestIpl.Create;

  BeginThread(nil, 0, Addr(RunThread), Addr(test), 0, ThreadId);
end;

{ Test }

function Test.Test: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

{ TestIpl }

function TestIpl.Test: Integer;
begin
  Result := 2;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Is is fine to cast pointer to object. But we cannot see all the picture. Where is `mtd` description? What it does? What `Test` does?

Comment: Yes. You're passing a pointer to your instance and then you're casting the raw pointer back to a class it descends from. This in itself should be no problem.

Comment: I updated the question and added mtd declaration. I see that obj after casting from Pointer is messed up in debugger ... (in memory)

Comment: @OndrejKelle Should be: "then I am casting the raw pointer back to a base class" is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant ("class it descends from" = "base class"). That's working fine.

Comment: @OndrejKelle  What's strange. Even If in BeginThread I pass "nil" as a parameter, I get parameter <> null in thread function body ....

Comment: Which probably means your `mtd` routine is declared incorrectly. It should have the signature of [`TThreadFunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TThreadFunc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your thread routine to be compatible with [`TThreadFunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.TThreadFunc) (as required by [`BeginThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.BeginThread)):

```
function mtd(Parameter: Pointer): Integer;
```

or, if you always pass a `Test` descendant to it you can simply declare it as such:

```
function mtd(Obj: Test): Integer;
```